VM connected to LAN but cannot reach host
I created a Windows11 VM using cockpit virtual-machine on a ubuntu server.
The network is configured as "Direct attachment" and the VM is reachable and can reach internet and all other workstation in the lan BUT not the host.
Some IPs:

Guest:   192.168.178.219
Host:    192.168.178.2
Internal DNS: 192.168.178.2
Gateway: 192.168.178.1

Routes
PS C:\Users\pp> route PRINT -4
===========================================================================
Interface List
  9...52 54 00 72 b7 d5 ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.178.1  192.168.178.219     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    192.168.178.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.178.219    281
  192.168.178.219  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.219    281
  192.168.178.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.219    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.178.219    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.219    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None



Please add the output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset from the host side. (Also ip a. Maybe "direct attachment" means macvtap?)

@TomYan it is

Direct attachment requires the use of the advanced switch behind the physical NIC, which supports quire extraordinary mode of port operation called VEPA. In that mode, the switch forwards back to the same port the packets that were received from that port; normal switch would never do that.
If you don't use such a switch or you haven't configured VEPA mode on the port connected to your host, your VMs wouldn't be able to communicate with each other and with the host.
To be able to do it without special switch, use bridge mode to attach the VM NIC to the network, instead of "direct attachment". That would require an additional configuration on the host side (create the bridge), that's normal, and anyway you had to make an additional configuration somewhere, on the switch or on the host. In the bridge mode your host will act as a virtual switch with (at least) three ports: physical NIC, the host itself and a port for the VM.

ok, that's out of my knowledge zone. The "direct" attachment was the only one working out of the box without additional configuration on the host. Is there a guide you would suggest on how to create the bridge and then attach the guest to it?
